# Results in columns without decimal places?

Tags: python, pandas

I have looked through a lot of posts, but none of the solutions I can implement in my code:

```
x4 = x4.set_index('grupa').T.rename_axis('DANE').reset_index().rename_axis(None,1).round()
```

After which I get the results DataFrame:

```
             DANE  BAKALIE  NASIONA  OWOCE  WARZYWA
0           ilosc      5.0     94.0   61.0    623.0
1     marza_netto      7.0    120.0   69.0    668.0
2  marza_procent2     32.0     34.0   29.0     27.0
```

But I would like to receive:

```
             DANE  BAKALIE  NASIONA  OWOCE  WARZYWA
0           ilosc        5       94     61      623
1     marza_netto        7      120     69      668
2  marza_procent2       32       34     29       27
```

I tried `replace('.0','')`,`int(round()`,`astype(int)`, but I don't get good results or I get the incompatibility of the attributes with the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only non numeric column is `DANE` then cast before convert to column:

```
x4 = x4.set_index('grupa')
       .T
       .rename_axis('DANE')
       .astype(int)
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None,1)
```

More general solution is select all floats columns and cast:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['float']).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)
print (df)
             DANE  BAKALIE  NASIONA  OWOCE  WARZYWA
0           ilosc        5       94     61      623
1     marza_netto        7      120     69      668
2  marza_procent2       32       34     29       27
```

---

If some `NaN`s values convert to `int` is not possible.

So is possible:

1.drop all NaNs rows:

```
df = df.dropna()
```

---

2.replace NaNs to some integer like `0`:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Actually, your solution is better, because it also does not change the character of the columns.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski - Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure I got your question, but you can use an `astype(int)` conversion.

```
df = df.set_index('DANE').astype(int).reset_index()
df

             DANE  BAKALIE  NASIONA  OWOCE  WARZYWA
0           ilosc        5       94     61      623
1     marza_netto        7      120     69      668
2  marza_procent2       32       34     29       27
```

If you're dealing with rows that have NaNs, either drop those rows and convert, or convert to `astype(object)`. The latter is not recommended because you lose performance.